# (Overloading) add two string in mathematical without atoi

Tags: c++, string

Assume that I have `My_string num1 = "123";` and `My_string num2 = "456";` I would like to add them and put it in to a new string for example `My_string ans;`so the result will be "579" without having to use `atoi` `stoi` (I want to do it in manual way)

I tried something like `ans = num1 + num2;` , what it does is just adding two strings together. I want to overload them so I can do `ans = num1 + num2;`

Any idea?

Comment: `without having to use atoi` Why this bizarre requirement? What's the purpose of the exercise? Anyway, if you don't like `atoi` specifically, there's [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: just for education purpose. I want to know if there is a manual way of overload it.

Comment: If `My_string` is your class, then yes, you can overload `operator+` and implement it however you want. Apparently, you already did, and implemented it as concatenation. Feel free to do something different instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I try to do something different but still don't come up with any idea yet. I can do something like casting but the result and the code just looks ugly to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty. Are you asking how to do [addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_arithmetic#Addition_algorithm) digit by digit, the way you were taught in elementary school?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes that is right. I'm thinking of using linked list but I don't think that's the way.

Comment: I don't know why I for arrow down for this question...just want to try something new

Comment: Why is a linked list not the way? What have you tried? What part doesn't work?

Comment: You can do it right from the strings.  Basically loop through them from the last character to the first. To do the addition the character - '0' is the integer. A stringstream is useful to build the new string.

Comment: @tinstaafl That actually sounds like a good idea. Could you please explain a bit more about this?

Comment: What part do you need help with?  All the concepts are fairly basic.  Any decent instructional material should be able to explain them much better than I could.  You should have enough of a concept to be able to try.  Don't be afraid of making mistakes that's how we learn.

Comment: @tinstaafl is it necessary to use stringstream?

Comment: It's a dynamic way of building a string.  Since strings are immutable concatenating them means building a brand new one each time. It's doable but in a high transaction app could be a drain on resources.

Answer (score 0):

use stringstream to read the string with << and then use >> to get integers. Then add them. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Answer (score 0):

something like this, you implement `atoi` by your self:

```
// assume your string only contain digit chars
My_string operator + (const My_string& s1, const My_string& s2) {
    My_string result;
    int number1 = 0;
    int strLen = s1.length();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strLen; ++i) {
        int d = (int)s1[i] - (int)'0';
        number1 += d * pow(10, strLen - i - 1);
    }

    int number2 = 0;
    // do the same thing as number1, you can wrap this as a method 'toNumber'
    ...

    int resultNumber = number1 + number2;
    // then convert result to My_string
    // you can call to_string directly or you write your own
    int remain;
    int v = resultNumber;
    while (v > 0) {
        remain = v % 10;
        v = v / 10;
        result.insert(result.begin(), (char)(0x30 + remain));
    }

    return result;
}
```